# jquery is not working in DNN 6.2.6

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

2.6 in my project development.I am in need of developing a directory structure using JQuery.When i tried to load jquery plugins as we do in normal web applications,its not working..When i tried same thing in a normal web application i got my required directory structure...

My Jquery settings in Host->Host settings are

Installed Jquery Version:1.7.2

installed Jquery UI Version:1.8.16

Use Jquery debug Version:Unchecked

Use Hosted Jquery Version:Unchecked

Hosted Jquery URL: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Hosted jquery UI URL: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

i hav tried to include

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration();
 DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestUIRegistration();
```

in the `Page_init` method but no use

also tried to include my jquery plugins as follows

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement"
    Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsInclude1" runat="server" FilePath="js/jquery.cookie.js"
    PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsInclude2" runat="server" FilePath="js/jquery.treeview.js"
    PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsInclude3" runat="server" FilePath="css/jquery.treeview.css"
    PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsInclude4" runat="server" FilePath="css/folderView.css"
    PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

but no use i hav searched many dnn discussions on this issue but no use..

Comment: Is your Page_init method getting hit in debug mode?

Comment: ya page_init method getting hit.and jquery files also getting loaded@Chris Hammond

Answer (score 2):

I know there is a priority when loading scripts using DnnJsInclude but the default value is 100 which is fine. Please see below regarding priority levels.

[DotNetNuke - Relative Order](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API.aspx#Relative_Order_10)

Using the **DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration** is the Page_Init or Page_Load should work fine. Try this and let me know if it works, also use something like firebug or even the Firefox developer console screen to see if your script is loading. Shortcut is (Ctrl+Shift+K). It should show you any errors loading the scripts.

I normally use the full path when adding CSS or Javascript resources.

**Please note that I'm using DnnCssInclude for css files and you are using DnnJsInclude for your folderView.css file.**

E.G

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" ID="jsBootstrap" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/MyModuleFolder/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" ID="cssBootstrap" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/MyModuleFolder/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: Now the script files are getting loaded.but still i am not able get the required jquery effect..@DNNDev.co.za

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the Priority attribute? This helped me solving issues more than once.

Check here: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API.aspx and search for "Relative Order".

Comment: Please see this questions previous answer as I've already advised Gajawada of this.